# match prefix between indexed fields when searching

Tags: java, search, lucene

Given the sample document below:

```
FIELD_A: [1_aa] [1_cc]
FIELD_B: [2_xx] [1_bb]
```

Query would be find something like:

```
find 'aa' in FIELD_A and 'xx' in FIELD_B
```

The query should match `FIELD_A` and `FIELD_B` on the prefix (example: `1_`) so the query above would not expect a result.

Does this make sense? And is this possible in Lucene or is there a better way to structure the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create seperate document for each prefix. Then using a conjunction query (`BooleanQuery` with `Occur.MUST` on both fields).

For example document `1_` :

`title:"1_"

FIELD_A: [aa] [cc]

FIELD_B: [bb]`

And document `2_` :

`title:"2_"

FIELD_B: [xx]`

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. There is a lot of data stored in the document that I don't want to duplicate so using this approach is there a 'nice' way to link the effective sub document to the main? Only way I can see this working is a double query.

Comment: I would store it away from the index if this doesn't have to be searchable, but if it does you could link it to the original `docId`.
Another option could be storing it in a different index.